# How to do VLOOKUP over every sheet in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, vlookup

I have Excel file, which will have many sheets (and I do not know their names right now - they will not follow any specific directive, they will represent dates of orders).

I have a column that represents article ID and another column that represents whether that specific article ID is missing or not (on that date - represented by sheet's name), here is the example

```
==Article ID==           ==Missing==
     1                       
     2                       Yes
     3
     4                       Yes

=======2nd July (sheet's name)===========================
```

The article IDs will be same in every sheet, and I want to create a summary sheet with all the article IDs and another column, which will contain names of sheets where the article ID is really missing.

I know how to use VLOOKUP, but can not find a way to use it to cover all the sheets as stated in the previous paragraph.

Comment: Can you please edit your question and mock up the expected result? Right now it is not clear what that should look like. Also consider that Vlookup may not be the best approach to achieve your desired outcome.

Comment: There is no formula that dynamically searches every sheet in the workbook. You can combine `INDIRECT()` with a list of sheet names to look for a value in every sheet that's in that list. You'd have to update that list as you add new sheets, though. I think any solution that doesn't have you updating a list of sheet names would involve Visual Basic.

Comment: It looks like you have created a second account, which will also interfere with your ability to comment within your thread and to accept an answer. See [How can one link/merge/combine/associate two accounts/users?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18232/how-can-one-link-merge-combine-associate-two-accounts) and/or [I accidentally created two accounts; how do I merge them?](https://superuser.com//help/merging-accounts) for guidance on how to merge your accounts.

Answer (score 0):

This is originally my question. The thing is i have an excel file with multiple sheets in it. Every sheet contains the same table with product number, name of the product and if the product was missing on the warehouse or not.

The thing i need to do is create a search tool, where i could type in the product number and it would show every sheet that contains the product number. I tried to do it through basic VLOOKUP, but i can´t mark more than one sheet. Also it would be nice if i could somehow achieve that whenever i put a new sheet in, i don´t need to manually change the search function.

Thank you

Comment: If it's your question, you need to log into the original profile you created, and edit the question.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! It looks like you have created a second account, which will also interfere with your ability to comment within your thread and to accept an answer. See [How can one link/merge/combine/associate two accounts/users?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18232/how-can-one-link-merge-combine-associate-two-accounts) and/or [I accidentally created two accounts; how do I merge them?](https://superuser.com//help/merging-accounts) for guidance on how to merge your accounts.